# Recognize application multitask-kill iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

Hee

Does anybody know how to recognize a multitask-kill.
When the user puts the application in background state and then kills the app through the menu in iOS 4.2 my application shuts down.
Before there used to be an function called:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

This method is not called anymore in iOS 4 and higher.
Is there a way to recognize it?

Thanks already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually that's not entirely true. It *is* called on iOS4 devices that do not support multi-tasking and the documentation says that it *can* be called on other handsets (though I've never seen it myself).

But to answer your question, no, you can't recognise when a user kills your app. If you have state that you want to save you need to do this when your app goes into the background and not when the app is killed.

If you look at the crash reports you'll see that iOS sends SIGKIL which you can't catch.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot catch this, your processed really is killed. Hard. Without notice. That us why you need to save state when you enter background now.

Maybe setting up a signal handler might work (don't know which signal to catch, though).

Comment: Well thats kinda crappy. Thanks for the reply.